# Should I store RAW file or DNG for backing up

Tags: raw, backup, dng

I have decided to store my photos for back-up. I am struggling with file type.
Should I store the RAW file that comes from camera or 
DNG file where all my editing has been stored.

Comment: how is your editing stored in the DNG? if it's about lightrooms metadata, you can save that as well in an XMP sidecar to your RAW.

Comment: yeah its generated from lightroom. how to export lightroom metadata to XMP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is switching to DNG worthwhile?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62/is-switching-to-dng-worthwhile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save DNG if you want, but you can also save RAW+XMP. (which would take significantly less space than RAW+DNG)

To export your Lightroom adjustments to an XMP sidecar file, either automatically or manually on demand, see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WS638E3AC9-A04C-4445-A0D3-F7D8BA5CDE37.html):

> 1.Choose Edit > **Catalog Settings** (Windows) or Lightroom > Catalog Settings (Mac OS).
>   2.Click the Metadata tab, and then do either of the following:
>   ◾ To write adjustments and settings metadata to XMP, select **Automatically
>   Write Changes Into XMP**.
>   ◾ To write adjustments and settings metadata only to the catalog,
>   deselect Automatically Write Changes Into XMP.
>
> If you don’t write adjustments and settings metadata to XMP
>   automatically, you can select a file and choose **Metadata > Save
>   Metadata To File**.

Another thing you should back up regularly is your Lightroom catalog, since that contains more than only the adjustments on the images (tags, histories mainly)