# I'm getting a green tint converting my Nikon NEF RAW files to DNG

Tags: nikon, raw, dng

I have a Nikon D5300

This problem just started this week, never happened before.

The problem: Everytime I convert a NEF file to a DNG the picture gets a green tint

Im using Adobe DNG Converter (updated to the latest version)

I recently also updated the NEF Codecs

Comment: Don't convert to DNG. Problem solved.

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/62/15871

Comment: > Everytime I convert a NEF file to a DNG the picture gets a green tint -- in what software it shows?

Comment: @Michael Clark : You are so right in fact.

Comment: I'm using Photoshop Elements 10

Comment: > I'm using Photoshop Elements 10 -- Dear Esteban, can you upload a sample DNG and an original NEF?

Comment: @Esteban Gutiérrez : Dear Esteban, can you upload a sample DNG and an original NEF?

Answer (score 1):

The general problem with converting from any raw format to DNG is there are often features that have not been ported or do not work well. It is expected that DNG will not work as well as the native raw format, unless the native raw format is already DNG.

In this particular case, the problem is likely related to white balance. Nikon may have issued a firmare update that changed the way the information is stored. Or Adobe may have introduced a bug in one of its updates.

Your options are:

- Wait until Adobe fixes the problem.
- Don't convert to DNG.
- Use the software that Nikon recommends.
- Adjust white balance manually.
- Switch to a better supported camera system.