# Lightroom: 'unexpected end of file occurred' - how to know which are the bad files?

Tags: lightroom

When applying a 'development' to a large number of photos in Lightroom, I sometimes get an error 'unexpected end of file occurred'. There is a lot of discussion in the internet about where this comes from and how to fix it, but my question here is:

*How do I find out which file(s) are the bad ones?*

Of course, stepping manually through all files will find it, but for a large number, this takes hours. Alternatively, i can re-run the setting change with the first half and then the second half, then with quarters, etc., basically a binary search. That is less manual action, but even more time.

Is there a way to make Lightroom go through *all* raw files in the catalog, and really *verify* each one's content (not just its existence), to find which ones are a problem, and give me the list (next morning or whenever)?

I have the newest version (subscription).

This question is related, but has another focus (and no solution): [How to find corrupt CR2 files?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85255/how-to-find-corrupt-cr2-files)

Answer (score 1):

If it actually are the physical files which are corrupt, you can try to batch convert them with imagemagick from the command line to some dummy file. It will complain about any problematic files.

Comment: Not a useful option; it is about 180000 files. Converting those would take days if not weeks.